# Can OrderBy evaluate delegate more than once for an element?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

A friend of mine said that the delegate function passed as parameter to OrderBy() in Linq is evaluated only once for every element. Consider the following case:

```
var list2 = list.OrderBy(item => item.ComputationallyExpensiveFunction()).ToList();
```

Is `ComputationallyExpensiveFunction()` really defined to be evaluated only once for every element in the list, or are there cases where it can be invoked more than once for the same item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OrderBy` calls the delegate once for each item, and caches the result.

I can't find mention of this behaviour in the docs, so I don't think it's *specified*, but the implementation does do this ([see referencesource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,2596)).

Answer (score 2):

Only once. You can confirm it by doing this:

```
var result = new int[] { 5, 3, 1, 4, 2 }.OrderBy(item =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    Console.WriteLine(item);
    return item;
});
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", result));
```

Output:

```
5
3
1
4
2
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```